# SQL Server compare data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to compare 2 columns in one SQL Table. Column1 has 012-0000430-001 and Column2 has 0120000430001 both nvarchar data types. I would like to run a compare to make sure both tables match.

```
select Column1,substring(Column2,1,3)
+ substring(Column2,5,7)
+substring(Column2,13,3)
from Table1
```

This query gives me the data but what could I do next to see which data matches and which does not. I would eventually like to create a trigger that find the mismatch and then correct it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare them, how about something like this?

```
select column1, column2,
       (case when column2 = replace(column1, '-', '') then 'same'
             else 'diff'
        end)
from table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select CASE WHEN replace(Column1,'-','')= Column2 then
'Equals' else 'Not Equals' end from Table_Name
```